# Google Map Lat Long issue.

Tags: php, google-maps

In PHP, I am able to search lat long from provided address. But In reverse case, If I search address from previously got lat long then it shows different result.
It means If I crossed check google map lat long and adress or vice versa both ways it shows different results

```
//Code to find Lat Long
$address = "My address, My city, Zipcode";
$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&sensor=false&region=India");
$json = json_decode($json);
$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};



//Code to find Address from lat long
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=lat,long
```

Above code suppose to return previously given $address. But it shows different addresses

Comment: That is the way it works, some addresses can not be validated that way.

Comment: So, Is there any accurate way?

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_lat_long($adrs)
    {
        $latlngArr="";
        $adrs=str_replace(" ", "+", $adrs);
        $str_add=file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$adrs."&sensor=false");
        $latlngArr["full_str"]=$str_add;

        $array_lat=explode("<lat>", $str_add);
        if(count($array_lat)>1)
        {
            $pos_lat=strpos($array_lat[1], "</lat>");
            $lat=substr($array_lat[1], 0, $pos_lat);
            $latlngArr["lat"]=$lat;
        }
        $array_lng=explode("<lng>", $str_add);
        if(count($array_lng)>1)
        {
            $pos_lng=strpos($array_lng[1], "</lng>");
            $lng=substr($array_lng[1], 0, $pos_lng);
            $latlngArr["lng"]=$lng;
        }

        return $latlngArr;
    }
```